# Writing a Macro In Cmake across CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

I have a project with a very simple directory sturcture like so,

```
--Top
  --Child
    CMakeLists.txt
  CMakeLists.txt
```

What I want to be able to do is define a macro in Top/CMakeLists.txt and then use it in Child/CMakeLists.txt.

What is the best way to do this?

I can link my exact lists if necessary, but the top level list contains,

```
...
include_directories (Sequences)
add_subdirectory (Sequences)

macro( ... )
endmacro( ... )
```

No matter what I do it seems like the macros I define only have local scope, and the documentation isn't very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried placing the macro definitions in front of the `add_subdirectory` call?

```
macro( ... )
endmacro( ... )
...
include_directories (Sequences)
add_subdirectory (Sequences)
```

Comment: No I did not, that would make to much sense! Thanks.